# Why was my flag as spam declined on this?

Tags: support, declined-flags, spam

I flagged this question as spam and was declined; why?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484831/what-do-you-think-i-am

Help me to understand here.

It's deleted. This is for <10k members.

Title:

> What do you think I am?

Post:

> I am 12 years old and I am going to be 13 this saturday

Comment: No links, no products or services mentioned -- it's garbage, but what makes it SPAM?

Comment: When you're not allowed to go out and tell your friends, SO is the second best option :D

Comment: That is not spam.  The definition of Spam that SO uses requires someone to be selling you something or promoting a product.  This does neither.  Very Low Quality would be more approrpriate

Comment: [What makes you think it falls under spam?](https://i.imgur.com/0qEXNmK.png)

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773)

Comment: @gnat It does not. I already accepted an answer. You probably flagged as such because of someone adding the "spam" tag to my question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner despite this, suggested duplicate has more correct answer than here because it suggests that improper spam flags on giberish posts are better to be disputed not declined. Worth noting that there is [recent discussion on this matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397177/839601) where people quite reasonably agrue that declining in cases like this does more harm than good

Comment: @gnat Fair enough. I just accepted the dupe.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Paul Roub's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397032/why-was-my-flag-as-spam-declined-on-this#comment767773_397032) is spot on.

It's garbage, but it's definitely not spam.

Comment: I flagged similar posts before and were never declined.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I would have declined the flag too. Reserve spam flags for promotional content/links.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Yeah, I get it now. Sorry if I wasted everyone's time on this. I'll know better next time, thanks.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner You might have been thinking of the [gibberish rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035). Red flags for those are fine, but if there's anything coherent close/downvote/delete

Comment: Someone edited my question and added the "spam" tag. I have to wonder if that should remain.

Comment: Is anyone going to answer my comment from above please? I feel ignored. Now someone posted a possible dupe.

Answer (score 3):

It's not spam, but sometimes moderators accept the flag (by just deleting the answer) just because they want it deleted *now*, when it's NAA/noise like in this case.

Now if you want to do it right, you want to delete & decline the flag as a moderator. So first you have to decline the flag (as deleting *validates* the flag). But in that case, the answer disappears from the moderator dashboard and you have to dig in your moderating history to find the flag and the original answer page. So it's better to navigate to the page first, decline the flag and delete.

When moderating from mobile for instance, a shortcut is taken by just clicking "delete" (I may have done this several times).

That explains why sometimes spam flags on NAA/nonsense are marked helpful (without the -100 penalty against the user) and sometimes not.

But the right thing to do was to decline and delete in this case.

Another possibility would have been to flag as "rude or abusive", as it is certainly abusive of the way the site works and the user probably knows it.