# Declined spam flag on gibberish question

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, spam

To those voting to close this as a duplicate of one of the questions linked here: Declining this flag represents a **change** in how flags are being handled by moderators. If there really is a change in how flags are going to be handled, then we should be made aware of it. Closing this as a duplicate implies that things are preceding as normal and established, that is not the case.

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590962) as spam, but my flag was declined:

[image]

The question was deleted by moderator action (score is > -6) as spam or rude/abusive (deleted and locked by the Community user) and the user has been deleted or destroyed. This indicates the moderator *specifically went out of their way* to decline my spam flag, while not declining other red-flags (presumably R/A flags) on the question.

For the past few/several years, the consensus has been that R/A flags are better on such posts, but that spam flags should be considered helpful. This is expressed in [Let's get aligned on how spam flags can be used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345332), [Is a post like 'assdddsssafffwq' spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310177), and [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035), among others.

- Why was my spam flag here declined?
- Declining spam flags on such posts appears to be a change in how such flags are handled. Should we expect that spam flags on similar posts will be declined in the future?
- Are spam flags going to be specifically declined by moderators on all R/A posts?

Comment: "Spam" has a specific meaning which involves promotion. Vandalism and garbage posts are not spam.

Comment: [This was gibberish though](https://i.imgur.com/RpLQlmV.png), which is red-flaggable.

Comment: @Zoe Yes, but the correct flag is R/A

Comment: Considering that both spam and rude flags are [handled the same way by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/323179) I’m not sure why we care so much about the distinction :p Choose “rude or abusive” next time for button mashes.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Closing this as a dup of the definition of spam, doesn't feel appropriate. For quite a while, the consensus has been that R/A flags are *better* on such posts, but that spam flags should be considered helpful. See [Let's get aligned on how spam flags can be used](/q/345332), [Is a post like 'assdddsssafffwq' spam?](/q/310177), and [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035), among others. Declining spam flags on such posts is a *change* in how flags are handled, which shouldn't just be a dup-closure.

Comment: If spam flags are to be declined on R/A posts, then we're going to need to make substantial changes to SmokeDetector and metasmoke, which only raise spam flags as autoflags (when appropriate). The Charcoal project has consistently stated that programmatically distinguishing between what should be flagged as R/A vs. spam is quite difficult. Given that the SE system handles spam and R/A flags nearly identically, the project has been quite resistant to putting in the work to differentiate those types for what is almost no benefit, other than to fit the semantic definition of each flag's name.

Comment: This supposed "consensus" that has been "established for years" is in conflict with how I have always interpreted Shog9's Meta post, and in conflict with how I process and interpret flags. So...it does not appear to be quite the "consensus" that commenters here have claimed. It's not outside the realm of possibility that I would have declined a spam flag on the linked post. When it's gibberish, don't flag it as spam. The meaning of "spam" is pretty obvious. If you are too lazy to make the distinction in such blatantly obvious cases, then perhaps you should leave the flagging to someone else.

Comment: @CodyGray "If you are too lazy to make the distinction in such blatantly obvious cases, then perhaps you should leave the flagging to someone else."... but [SO is still one of the most welcoming places on the entire Internet, yes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347104/introducing-the-moderator-council-and-its-first-pro-tempore-representatives?cb=1#comment1162065_347161)

Comment: @CodyGray A quick look at the last 100 SmokeDetector/metasmoke (SD/MS) autoflagged posts shows 21 of them were on R/A content. Of those, 9 were gibberish. IMO, leaving the volunteers who allow SD/MS to use their accounts for autoflagging open to 21% of their SO flags being declined would breach the trust of those volunteers. If spam flags are to be declined on R/A posts, then the only responsible thing to do for SD/MS is to completely disable autoflagging on Stack Overflow, until SD/MS can accurately distinguish between spam and R/A content, so the semantically correct flag can be raised.

Comment: @CodyGray _The meaning of "spam" is pretty obvious_ -- I couldn't disagree more. It is only obvious for those who handled and cast hundreds spam flags over here. For vast majority of less experienced users spam flags at SO are [unusually strict](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287283/165773). And before lazily declining these you better recall guidance in [old moderator newsletter](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/), "try to err on the side of clearing as `[helpful]` whenever the user is trying to be genuinely helpful..."

Comment: @CodyGray I realized my prior comment may be misunderstood. I don't feel *you* are breaching the trust SD/MS volunteers have given. I feel that *I*, as a custodian of that trust, would be breaching it by allowing autoflagging to continue on SO when there's the likelihood a large number of autoflags on SO will be declined (up to ~20%). People allow SD/MS to use their flags with the understanding the flags will be used with a *very* high degree of accuracy (99.75% is the *lowest* it's possible to choose). Allowing autoflagging to continue when I know that may not be met would not be responsible.

Comment: Well, [once upon a time even a rude/abusive flag on these kind of posts got declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342847/4751173) ...